# Should "Search Query and Site Settings Service" run on all servers in a SP2013 farm?

Tags: 2013, search, configuration

I've got a SharePoint 2013 farm of 6 servers configured like this:

1. SQL Server (Clustered)
2. SQL Server (Clustered)
3. Front End (Load balanced)
4. Front End (Load balanced)
5. Search Query, Central Admin, some other services
6. Search Crawl, Content Processing, some other services

I have noticed that the *Search Query and Site Settings Service* is running on all 4 SharePoint servers. I have also noticed a worryingly large number of log entries along the lines of: `Tried IMS endpoints for operation Execute: Operation sent to IMS failed: Resource saturation, try again later.` and `Active Endpoints: 3 Failed Endpoints:1 Affected Endpoint: http://box_6`... Which worries me as `box_6` should only be running the crawl and content processing, not answering queries.

Would stopping the *Search Query and Site Settings Service* on the other 3 boxes be a good idea?

Will just stopping it via *Manage services on server* be enough, or do I need to unprovision it via powershell?

Am I missing anything obvious? / Is the problem somewhere else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/12/09/sp2010-search-query-load-balancing-explained-part-2.aspx (see the special note on SharePoint 2013)

As per the article in *SP2013* you can stop SQ&SS on 3 servers, and just leave it running on the server running on Query Processing Component.

you can stop it using Manage services on server

Comment: Thank you. That was a very helpful pair of articles and definitively answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at MS's tech diagrams for SP2013, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199(v=office.15).aspx, there's a lot of useful layouts and architecture examples here.

To answer your question, no, I generally don't put Query on all boxes, just a couple of dedicated ones, or in your case, on both app servers. It depends on the hardware specs of the servers, but I generally keep the front ends as front ends, no additional services, and run search on a separate pair of services and all remaining services on another pair (I know you don't have that much hardware), but as an example.

Comment: Thank you. While it did not directly solve my problem, the resources there did give me a much better understanding of how to distribute services.